# Horizontal Scrolling for images in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

i am making a webapp in jquery mobile for android, iOS, windows and web. I have a page in this app in which i want to show just 1 image. I want that user should be able to pinch-zoom, and so i want horizontal scrolling in that page so that full image can be viewed easily. Zoom feature can be enabled by user-scalable in meta viewport..but i am unable to enable horizontal scrolling. How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="imageDiv" style="height:500px ;width:auto;overflow:auto;"></div>
```

With the overflow property, you will be able to move the image using your finger :)
It works for me on iPad.

Hope it helps.